# Karate: How to turn a list of lists into a single list?

Tags: javascript, karate

I have a list of lists in Karate that looks like:
[[elemtna], [abc], [bcd]]

I'd like to convert this list into a single list like: [elemtna, abc, bcd]

I tried the following code with no success:

- def mylist = existingList.map(x => x.map(y => String(y)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `flat()` method:

```
[['elemtna', 'doc', 'third'], ['abc'], ['bcd']].flat() // returns ['elemtna', 'doc', 'third', 'abc', 'bcd']
```